What are the pros & cons of downdraft ventilation?
I'm looking at replacing my cooktop sometime within the next few months.  One of the things I dislike about my current one is the exhaust hood, so when I heard about downdraft ventilation my interest was piqued.
The main advantage of downdraft ventilation seems to be exactly that there is no hood or other equipment above the cooking surface, but are there any others?
And what about drawbacks?  For example,

Are these systems robust against spills into the vent?

Are they as effective as overhead ventilation (at the same noise level)?

Do they take up a lot of space underneath the cooktop?



The only benefit to a downdraft extractor is appearance over an overhead extractor. I have a downdraft extractor and used others, I can definitely say they are not as effective as overhead. Heat rises, so the most effective way to capture cooking smoke and odors is to place the extractor directly above the cooking surface. Backdraft ones only are effective at extracting from pans on the rear burners. However, those are limitations I've learned to live with as it means I don't have to have a giant extractor over my island, and it does well enough when I need it.
You lose the two cupboards that the mechanism is housed in, although there some space around the mechanism. That's not that different from losing the cupboards above where an overhead extractor would be so it's a zero sum game.
The mechanisms for raising and lowering are not that robust, they can stick or get stuck and repairing them can be a real pain. Keeping the whole thing clean helps keep food grease from getting into the mechanism.

Another issue with fancy extractor kinds such as downdraft is replaceability. When the extractor eventually gives up the ghost for good, it will likely be quite hard to find a replacement with exactly matching mounting dimensions to fit into the existing hole and cupboards. Replacing a standalone overhead extractor with a similar one is trivial.

Also, given the uncertain efficiency of downdraft extractors, if you mount cabinets above the cooktop, they will probably end up all sticky and greasy at some point. So it's not necessarily a zero-sum game.


Heat Rises
Smoke Rises

Those are two big reasons for me why an exhaust fan hood makes much more sense than a downdraft fan. Plus it just makes more sense to me. But, in theory at least, a downdraft fan, if powerful enough, can work just fine. A few things to keep in mind:

Open gas burners

At least one model I checked (a GE) says in the specifications that it can be used with electric (coil or induction) or sealed gas burners but not open gas burners. I'm not sure why, but that is one thing to keep in mind as apparently open gas burners are still a preference among some cooks (I like my sealed burners just fine, thank you).

Ductwork

This is a big one. For a hood or downdraft with a cooktop on an outside wall there shouldn't be much of an issue with ductwork. However, for an island - which is often a common scenario for a downdraft exhaust fan, ductwork can get much more complicated than a hood. With a hood, either up and out if there is no living space above, or up to the ceiling and out to the side of the building. With a downdraft fan you need to go down into the floor and then somehow out to the side of the building. There are specs (often included in installation instructions) for how much each piece of non-straight ductwork counts towards the maximum total "length" specified for a particular fan. Figure that out before making a decision, as it could really complicate matters.

Variable Speed

With both a hood and a downdraft fan, you generally have multiple fan speeds available. I run my hood fan on the lowest speed 98%+ of the time that it is running, but I know I have the extra speed/airflow when needed due to cooking problems. I would expect a decent downdraft to be similar.

Noise

It is not always easy, but try to compare specs for sound (typically in decibels or sones) and airflow (typically CFM) at both low speed (which you will likely want to use most of the time) and high speed. I actually wouldn't worry about noise at high speed, but airflow and low and high and noise at low all affect usability.

Open gas burners are typically quite sensitive to any sideways airflow (sometimes to the point where a strong draft from an open window on a windy day can make the "windward" side of the burner lose flame altogether). Downdraft extractors create nothing but sideways airflow.

All the downdraft extractors that I've seen (central/northern Europe) have a carbon filter and recirculate the air back into the room. That is never as efficient as extracting the air to the outside. And changing the filters becomes an expensive chore.

@Popup A recirculating filter as you describe is theoretically fine for grease and smoke, but it does nothing for carbon dioxide and - far more important - carbon monoxide. Downdraft exhaust is OK, except for my concerns stated above.
